# Vue.js - Issue with Menu Component and Event Handling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuex

I'm currently working on a Vue.js project and have encountered an issue with a custom menu component. The menu is supposed to handle sorting types, and I'm using it in conjunction with a method (setSortingType) to update the sorting type when an item is selected. However, I'm facing a problem where the selected property in the event object ($event) is not behaving as expected

```
<menu
    ref="MenuRef"
    :items="SortTypes"
    target="#sorting-button"
    position="center"
    @clicked-away="isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked"
    @selected="setSortingType"
/>
```

---

```
const SortTypes = [{labek: 'l1'}, {label: 'l2'}]

setSortingType($event) {
    // some code
}
```

---

The dropdown is properly displaying the items. and I was able to click them.
But if I select the `item1` initially and then if I open dropdown and click on the `item2`, the dropdown is closing (which is fine).

But when I select the `item1` and then if I open dropdown and click on the same `item1` again, it's not closing the dropdown. It's not even calling the method mentioned in `@selected` event.

I even tried with `@click`. Still not working.
Where am I doing wrong.

Comment: It depends on how the custom component works, which we have no idea.  Please add the relevant code of the `menu` component, specifically the code that shows how these different events fire.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The main app was using a shared library. I had to update it. No issues now.